# How to use handler as a timer in android?

Tags: android, timer, handler

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();    
    if (v.getId() == R.id.play){    
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {                    
       public void run() {
           play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ilk);
       }
   }, 2000);    
       play.setText("Play");    
}
```

I want to set background first and then after 2 seconds later, code will continue next line which is `play.setText("Play");` and goes like that. Instead of this, first text appears. 2 seconds later background changes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Ok thanks. my problem is independent from code i will upload this code as a example. I just wonder about that is there a metod like that delay(second); which I can use between any code block.

Answer (score 9):

`Handler.postDelayed` returns immediately. And next line is executed.
After indicated milliseconds, the `Runnable` will be executed.

So your code should be like this:

```
void doFirstWork() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    if (v.getId() == R.id.play){

       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               play.setText("Play");
               doNextWork();
           }
       }, 2000);

       play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ilk);
    }
}

void doNextWork() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok. I got this but what I want is that after Handler.postDelayed is executed, the code will continue next line because there are many code blocks in there. Is there any method like that?

Comment: I updated my answer. Blocking UI Thread is unti-pattern in Android development.  If you block the UI Thread, users will frustrated. .

Answer (score 1):

Set the background first. After that set the text within Handler. As you've put delays at the end of postDelayed so it'll fire right after that stated delays or in your case after 2 sec.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.play){
   play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ilk);
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           play.setText("Play");
       }
   }, 2000);

}
```